# How do I retain my button selection state for my webpage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The webpage is created with asp.net mvc, javascript, razor and jQuery
I have some buttons that filters the view display list.

Use case: When user clicks on any filter and press apply, the page reloads the view with the filtered display list of data.

Issue: Right now my after performing the above use case, the button selected will be auto cleared. Is there a way to save the button state?

Desired outcome
Example: I perform the use case, click on button1 and click on apply button next. Page and list refreshes but the button1 is still selected.

Is there a need to use cookies?
I do not understand the concept of how to save my data via cookies from c# or javascript.

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("pending");

if(cookie == null)
{
    cookie = new HttpCookie("pending");
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("pending");
    HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);

}
```

From google chrome's ctrl + shift + i, I can see that there is a cookie but I am unsure on where do I locate the cookie file saved at and what data it has inside it.

Below is the button implementation.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#filterPending').checkboxradio();
        $('#filterDirect').checkboxradio();
        $("#sort-selection").selectmenu({ width: 270 });
        $('#ApplyFilter').click(function () {
            var params = "";

            if ($('#filterPending')[0].checked) {

                params = params + "filters=pending";
            }
            if ($('#filterDirect')[0].checked) {
                if (params !== "") {
                    params = params + "&";
                }
                params = params + "filters=direct";
            }

            window.location.href = "?" + params;
        });
    });
</script>
@{
    bool isFilterByPending = ViewBag.FilterByPending;
    bool isFilterByDirect = ViewBag.FilterByDirect;
    string checkedPending = ViewBag.FilterByPending ? "checked" : "";
    string checkedDirect = ViewBag.FilterByDirect ? "checked" : "";
}
<label for="filterPending">Pending</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filterPending" id="filterPending" @checkedPending>
```

Comment: I'd use a partial view or bind the selected button to the view model to retain the selection. No need for cookies.

Comment: Is there any links I can reference to this?

Comment: Post your markup for your button please so I see how you are indicating a "selected" state

Comment: posted the cshtml side.

Comment: This is just javascript  =)  You're losing your stuff because you're using script instead of submitting to the page like usual mvc so your ViewBag will always have its initial values. Was there a reason you chose to do it this way? I don't want to advise you to totally change how you're doing this if you did it for a reason.

Comment: I was told to do it this way, so its hard to make changes now since the web services is already live now. So I have to find any way to make sure the button states are saved. 
The C# parts handle the sql part and sorting/filtering and return the correct view and other view functionalities.

Comment: okay. well, it is what it is. Change this statement to check your url as well as your viewbag bool isFilterByPending = ViewBag.FilterByPending; so that the presence in the url overrides the viewbag

Comment: I think I don't get what you mean hmm.....